npm error Invalid: lock file's typescript@5.7.2 does not satisfy typescript@4.9.5
Ive tried a variety of solutions I've found on here but cannot seem to by pass this error or correct it.
For background I am new to typescript and was attempting to create a basic skeleton react-typescript app and deploy it to github pages using github actions. Here is my package.json:
  "name": "omscs-portfolio-react-typescript-githubpages",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "homepage": "https://akaufman3.github.io/omscs-portfolio-react-typescript-githubpages/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.96",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^8.17.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^8.17.0",
    "eslint": "^9.16.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.28.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "react-scripts": {
      "typescript": "^5"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^5.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  }
}

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Ive verified npm, node, etc are all updated correctly and it seems I cant force react-scripts to use typescript 5. Thanks
